# React-Navigation: Cannot hide header with nested navigators

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using the official [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org) to handle my navigation. I have one main TabNavigator for the whole app with two tabs (called `HitchhikingMapNavigator` and `SettingsNavigator` below), and each tab has a nested StackNavigator:

```
const HitchhikingMapNavigator = StackNavigator({
  hitchhikingMap: { screen: HitchhikingMapViewContainer },
  spotDetails: { screen: SpotDetailsViewContainer }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    header: {
      visible: false
    }
  }
});

const SettingsNavigator = StackNavigator({
  // some other routes
});

export default AppNavigator = TabNavigator({
  hitchhikingMap: { screen: HitchhikingMapNavigator },
  settings: { screen: SettingsNavigator }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    header: {
      visible: false,
    },
 },
});
```

As you can see, I put the headers' visilibility to false everywhere, even in my `HitchhikingMapViewContainer`'s view:

```
class HitchhikingMapView extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Map',
    header: {
      visible: false,
    },
    //...other options
  }
```

And yet, the header bar is still visible:

[image: screenshot]

If I don't nest the navigators (i.e. if I put this code, skipping the nested one):

```
export default AppNavigator = TabNavigator({
  hitchhikingMap: { screen: HitchhikingMapViewContainer },
  settings: { screen: SettingsNavigator }
});
```

then the header is correctly hidden.

So conclusion: I can't make a header not visible when I have two nested navigators. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For those who are still looking for the answer, I will post it here.

So two solutions:

1st solution: use `headerMode: 'none'` in the StackNavigator. This will remove the header from ALL screens in the StackNavigator

2nd solution: use `headerMode: 'screen'` in the StackNavigator and add `header: { visible: false }` in the `navigationOptions` of the screens where you want to hide the header.

More info can be found here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: As for React Navigation 1.0.0-beta.11 header : { visible : false} doesn't work. Use header : null instead.

Answer (score 11):

Starting from `v1.0.0-beta.9`, use the following,

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```js
headerMode: 'none'
```

Comment: doesn't work for me in `"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7"`

Comment: I have "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.9" and the method  -> static navigationOptions = {    header: false  } work for me.

Comment: @DanielArenas You're my hero dude

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me, i am working on android side in react native version 0.45

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me to hide the navigation:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
 };
```